# Python multithreading inside class

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have the following class ParserList which takes a list of parsers (class Parser). Each parser parses different files located in different folders.

```
class ParserList(list):
    '''
    List of Parser objects.
    Can parse multiple files at once.
    '''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParserList, self).__init__(args[0])
        self.records = RecordList([])

    def parse(self):
        #Launch threads to parallelize log processing
        for p in self:
             t = threading.Thread(target = p.parse())
             t.daemon = True
             t.start()

class Parser(object):
      ....
```

Why doesn't multithreading work in this case ?

Timing this shows longer timings than if I only had:

```
def parse(self):
    for p in self:
        p.parse()
```

Comment: It depends pretty heavily on whether or not your parsing is IO Bound or Processor Bound.  If it's IO Bound then threading can help because it lets you continue working while waiting on some IO Completion, but if it's Processor Bound you're going to get unwanted interaction with the GIL.  The body of `Parser.parse` would be worth seeing here, but there's a lot of information about your implementation that will affect whether or not threading can be used to speed things up for you.

Comment: Also note: The GIL was generally less performant in Python 2 (which, based on your explicit passing of arguments to `super` and explicit inheritance from `object`, you're probably using). [In Python 3.2+, GIL contention is usually resolved with less overhead (and many of the `threading` types like `Condition`s are _much_ lower overhead than that in certain cases, e.g. timed acquires)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#multi-threading). So even if you were getting some benefit from working while other threads were blocked on I/O, later GIL contention could be eating the savings.